# Doesn't able to run job(kjb) in Pentaho Data Integration 9.2

Tags: etl, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I have tried running job using pentaho 9.2 it is not picking the job when running by kitchen comment

**./kitchen.sh -rep=repo1 -file=/var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/Job1.kjb**

Job1.kjb contains multiple sub_jobs. Pentaho 9.2 is not picking the sub job and showing following error.

**Error Log:**

2022/03/02 05:00:28 - Job1 - Start of job execution
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - Job1 - Starting entry [sub_job_1]
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Error running job entry 'job' :
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
**2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Unexpected error during job metadata load
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Unable to load the job from XML file [/var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.kjb.kjb]**
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - File [file:///var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.kjb.kjb] does not exists.**
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta(JobEntryJob.java:1467)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta(JobEntryJob.java:1385)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.execute(JobEntryJob.java:695)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:693)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:834)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:503)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -   at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:389)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Unable to load the job from XML file [/var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.kjb.kjb]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing much details, but maybe the problem is that in your *Job1.kjb* job you have not defined correctly the location of the subjob. In the log it's saying that it cannot find the file:

/var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.**kjb.kjb**

Probably your subjob is the file: /var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.**kjb**