# My pentaho ETL jobs(.kjb) files are not working after upgrading the pentaho data integeration from 5.3 to 9.2

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

I used to run the Pentaho ETL jobs in PDI community edition 5.3 with the kitchen like below

**./kitchen.sh -rep=repo1 -file=/var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/Job1.kjb**

after upgrading the PDI community edition to 9.2 the same ETL jobs are showing the below errors

```
**Error Log:**

2022/03/02 05:00:28 - Job1 - Start of job execution
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - Job1 - Starting entry [sub_job_1]
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : Error running job entry 'job' :
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - ERROR (version 9.2.0.0-290, build 9.2.0.0-290 from 2021-06-02 06.36.08 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:
**2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Unexpected error during job metadata load
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Unable to load the job from XML file [/var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.kjb.kjb]**
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - File [file:///var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.kjb.kjb] does not exists.**
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 -
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta(JobEntryJob.java:1467)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.getJobMeta(JobEntryJob.java:1385)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - at org.pentaho.di.job.entries.job.JobEntryJob.execute(JobEntryJob.java:695)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:693)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:834)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:503)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:389)
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException:
2022/03/02 05:00:28 - sub_job_1 - Unable to load the job from XML file [/var/lib/jenkins/project/path/etl/sub_job_1.kjb.kjb]
```

**the error is its additionaly adding the .kjb extension at end of each job**

Answer (score 0):

The question is duplicated, as I have already asked in [Doesn't able to run job(kjb) in Pentaho Data Integration 9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71317901/doesnt-able-to-run-jobkjb-in-pentaho-data-integration-9-2), have you ckecked that in Job1.kjb the entry pointing to sub_job_1 has the correct path? Have you tried editing Job1.kjb using Pentaho 9.2 and manually reentering the path to sub_job_1 to ensure that the extension .kjb isn't duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem now currently.

It's really weird, I'm not sure why but it only breaks when I have a job, and then there are job steps within the job. It does not break for transformation steps that are calling another transformation.

What is even weirder is when I edit the file path for some jobs, it fixes them, but I don't have to do that to all job steps or if I do it to some steps, the step is still broken despite the file exists.

I will edit this post if I learn more, but that's all I have learned for now.

Not sure why a moderator deleted my earlier post, would love an explanation.

Anyhow, When I put the full path into the job step, everything worked fine. I recommend doing that, and you should be good to go.